# how to show image style with private file system? 403 access denied error occurs

Tags: media, files

I'm working on a webapp and changed my public file system in to a private file system. Everything works fine, except my thumbnails created by image styles throwing a **403 Access denied error**.

Does anyone know how to fix this, without removing the private check in image.module in core??

private file system check in image.module

```
if ($scheme == 'private') {
    if (file_exists($derivative_uri)) {
      file_download($scheme, file_uri_target($derivative_uri));
}
```

Thanks